# Playing and recording media simultaneously in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I want to play an mp3 file from speaker phone and record by microphone simultaneously. I used the code below to route an audio from earpiece to speakerphone:

```
AudioRoutingManager audioManager = AudioRoutingManager.GetDefault();
audioManager.SetAudioEndpoint(AudioRoutingEndpoint.Speakerphone);
```

but it made my app crash. I follow this post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matthew_van_eerde/archive/2014/03/17/a-mental-model-for-the-windows-phone-audioroutingmanager-api.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I did try add this

```
AudioRoutingManager.GetDefault().AudioEndpointChanged += MainPage_AudioEndpointChanged;
```

and

```
private void MainPage_AudioEndpointChanged(AudioRoutingManager sender, object args)
{
    AudioRoutingManager.GetDefault().SetAudioEndpoint(AudioRoutingEndpoint.Speakerphone);
}
```